# include html in html with functions and css

Tags: php, html, css, function, include

I have a page made of a header bar and a navigation bar.

I want to include this parts into all of my subpages of my website without redoing it all over again.

For this, I´m using this code inside my index.php file of the main page:

```
<?php include '../folder/folder/index.php';?>
```

The html inclution works fine with this code. But when I click the navigation buttons, the functions for the buttons, which are in a separat javascript.js file are not called. It looks inside my current directory and not the one of the included file. Same with the stylesheet.css file of the navigation and header bar.

Any help please?

Thank you for your time.

Best regards!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Yeah I think you may need to share a snippet of your attempt. Anyways just check if you've got your relative path right on the instances where you use the `include()`. `'../folder'` might be true once and `'../../folder'` may also be true depending of the location the you're in.

Comment: it might be a good idea to use **absolute paths**... `<script src="http://example.com/js/myscript.js"></script>` or `<script src="/js/myscript.js"></script>`

Comment: Thank you that was the thing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Includes are just chunks of code inserted into other files. So links and pages are going to be relative to the page including/housing the include tag...  Say the file you're including looks like:

***examp.com/common/include.php***

```
<a href="index.php">Home</a>
```

If we include that file from ***examp.com/test.php*** then it will link to ***examp.com/index.php***.

But if we include that same file from ***examp.com/folder/folder/dude.php*** it will link to ***examp.com/folder/folder/index.php*** because that's where the relative link goes.

To fix this, you *could* use absolute links...

***examp.com/common/include.php***

```
<a href="http://examp.com/index.php">Home</a>
```

Now the include will ALWAYS point to that specific location on that specific domain.  What I suggest using is a "/" before your link, to make the link start at the root of the domain.

***examp.com/common/include.php***

```
<a href="/index.php">Home</a>
```

In the above, the included file will always point to the index.php in the root of your domain: ***examp.com/index.php*** no matter where's included from.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening cause you probably include the js and css something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/mystyle.css">
```

You're looking for the directory of the file thats being included.:

`__DIR__` :     **The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.**

[Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)